# Как правильно вычисляется шаг?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Мне в пятом классе задали контрольную: нарисовать окружность ровно за 4 секунды.
Я нарисовал за полторы, но не понял почему... если расстояние `/` на на время `=` скорость,
а расстояние я узнал разогнув кружок вот так: `Math.PI * 2 * radius`, то почему в коде ниже это ничего не работает?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

var clicked = false
var angle = 0
var radius = 40
var time = 4000

addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (clicked) return

  clicked = true
  setTimeout(() => {
    angle = 0
    clicked = false
  }, time)
})

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  if (clicked) {
    angle += Math.PI * 2 * radius / time
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, radius, 0, angle, false)
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

var clicked = false
var angle = 0
var radius = 40
var duration = 4000
var startTime = 0

addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (clicked) return

  startTime = Date.now()
  clicked = true

  setTimeout(() => {
    angle = 0
    clicked = false
  }, duration)
})

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  if (clicked) {
    var v = Math.PI * 2 * radius / duration
    var t = (Date.now() - startTime) / duration
    angle += t * v
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, radius, 0, angle, false)
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

var clicked = false
var angle = 0
var radius = 40
var duration = 4000
var startTime = 0

addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (clicked) return

  startTime = Date.now()
  clicked = true

  setTimeout(() => {
    angle = 0
    clicked = false
  }, duration)
})

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  if (clicked) {
    var v = Math.PI * 2 * radius / duration
    var t = (Date.now() - startTime) / duration
    angle = t * v * 100
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(innerWidth / 2, innerHeight / 2, radius, 0, angle, false)
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}

 requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Функция в requestAnimationFrame запускается браузером примерно 60 раз в секунду. Каждый раз `angle` увеличивается на `PI * 2 * 40 / 4000` ≈ `0.06283` радиан. Полный круг это `PI * 2` ≈ `6.283` радиан, и если функция вызывается 60 раз в секнуду, то такое значение будет достигнуто спустя `6.283 / 0.06283 / 60` ≈ `1.67` секунд — именно это мы и наблюдаем.

Comment: «Мне в пятом классе» и 129 хороших ответов на ruSO как-то не очень соотносятся... 

Comment: @andreymal  я поздно в школу пошел. Ну хорошо, у тупика есть имя, а что дальше-то делать?

Comment: В момент клика запоминать текущее время, а внутри draw считать длительность, прошедшую с момента клика, и в расчётах опираться на эту длительность

Comment: это что школьное задание ? это canvas в школе учат ?

Comment: @MaximLensky в моей выдуманной школе можно найти себе занятия по вкусу.

Comment: @andreymal я сдаюсь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. В формуле для угла - радиус явно лишний
2. Время уже Вам передается первым аргументом, 
   если Вы используете requestAnimationFrame:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var radius = 50;

function draw(t) { // тут передается время в мс
  
  t /= 4000; // t станет больше одного, через 4000 мс
             // соответственно 1 = полный круг
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150, 75, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * t, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  t < 1 && requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: А что с этой формулой v = s / t ? Я просто читаюто сновы, пытаюсь применить в программировании, но это требует еще каких-то дополнительных манипуляций с результатом...

Comment: @hu-fo что за v и s?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, скорость и путь очевидно :)

Comment: @Grundy я догадываюсь, но все же не совмес очевидно

Comment: Скорость = расстояние / время

Comment: @hu-fo со если работать со скоростью, то ее надо умножать на дельту времени, то есть на разницу t между кадрами и получать приращение координаты

Comment: Добавил вариант в вопрос. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так, у меня получилось(3 вариант), но всё равно как-то неправильно...

Comment: @hu-fo почему не правильно?

Comment: Проблема в том, что время начинается не с нуля. Я сделал console.log — у меня начинается где-то с 400мс. Соответственно и окружность начинает рисоваться не с начала анимации. Так что я бы предпочёл старое доброе запоминание текущего времени вручную :)

Comment: @andreymal да, там время с начала выполнения скрипта на странице..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ то есть вы точно так же сделали бы?

Comment: @hu-fo я бы не стал пользоваться скоростью, там где достаточно линейной интерполяции, но если вплетать скорость - то надо уж не вычилсять и перезаписывать угол каждый раз `angle = t * v * 100` а действовать приращениями `angle += v*deltaT`, это позволяет иметь переменную скорость в разных кадрах, например

Comment: Моё `t` - `(Date.now() - startTime) / duration` и `deltaT`  это не одно и то же?

Comment: дельта т это разница времени между кадрами, сколько прошло с прошлой отрисовки, соответственно на основании него можно посчитть на сколько сместился объект, зная его скорость в этот момент

Comment: @hu-fo https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106467/webgl-glsl может в чат?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, `requestAnimationFrame` нужен ли при рисовании в `canvas` ? почему не интервал

Comment: @qwabra интервал, можно и его но лучше requestAnimationFrame, с ним браузер ловко управляется, например для неактивной вкладки он может не вызываться вообще, или быть прореженным, зависит от браузера, бережет батарею